# What does the comment /** @jsx jsx */ do in the Emotion CSS-in-JS library?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

This seems to be a best practice, since it is used almost everywhere. However, nowhere is it clearly explained what exactly it does ...

I did find a comment in the [docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/install) that said: 
"This comment tells babel to convert jsx to calls to a function called jsx instead of React.createElement". Does this simply mean it replaces standard React functionality with Emotion's? Are there any consequences from leaving out the /** @jsx jsx */ comment?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a [custom pragma](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#custom) that tells the jsx transformer, in this case `babel-plugin-transform-react` what function to use to transform your jsx into plain javascript.

From the [React Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html):

A React component using jsx that looks like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.toWhat}</div>;
  }
}
```

Will be transformed into this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  }
}
```

But by using that custom pragma, the compiled js might look like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return jsx('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  }
}
```

This is useful because the `jsx` function might in some way enable the functionality of the library you're using by modifying or otherwise using the props or other data passed in from the jsx.

So therefor the answer to this question:

> Are there any consequences from leaving out the /** @jsx jsx */

is yes. It will probably break the functionality of the library.

**EDIT**

This is mentioned in emotion's docs here: https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma

Comment: When I initially tested with a simple example whether leaving the pragma out broke anything, nothing changed. But I retested it now with more features, and it indeed breaks. So thank you for the elaborate answer!

Comment: I am unsure if it needs to be applied to every jsx file for the library to work correctly, or can it be applied selectively to files with components that import `@emotion/core`. `@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop` seems to replace the jsx function on every file (or at least the files I've examined) even if emotion was not imported. Are there any issues/overhead with a wholesale replacement of the jsx function with emotion's?

Answer (score 9):

The emotion [`jsx` export](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/master/packages/core/src/jsx.js#L20) allows you to put the `css` prop on any component, and have it automatically converted into a className prop.

[`/** @jsx jsx */`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#custom) tells Babel to call the `jsx` variable instead of `React.createElement`, which you just imported from emotion